# Handlebars {{each}} inside of {{#times}}

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, handlebars.js

```
                    <form action="/ayarlar/league/edit-{{this}}/{{../league._id}}?_method=PUT" method="POST" class="boxInfo">
                        <div class="grupDiv"
                            style="width:150px;display:inline-block;border:1px solid black;padding:10px">
                            <h2>Grup {{this}}</h2>
                            <select name="groupNo{{this}}" id="" multiple>
                                {{#each team}}
                                <option value="{{_id}}">{{teamName}}</option>
                                {{/each}}
                            </select>
                            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
                            <button type="submit" class="redButton">Kaydet</button>

                            <p><span style="color:red">Takımlar : </span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    {{/times}}
```

When I try to run this code it doesn't work. However, when I delete the {{#times}} block, the code is correctly working. Also I defined the times helper like this :

```
const hbs = exphbs.create({
    helpers: {
        times: function(n, block) {
            let accum = '';
            for (let i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
                accum += block.fn(i);
            return accum;
        },
        eq: function (a, b) {
            return a === b;
        }
    }
});
```

I want to have each `teamName` rendered as an option, but none are.

Comment: What does your data look like ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that when you are *inside* the block wrapped by `{{#times league.groupNumber}} {{/times}}`, the context - ie., the `this` - is current value passed to `block.fn` in your `times` helper, which is a Number. (This is why `<h2>Grup {{this}}</h2>` results in something like `<h2>Grup 1</h2>`)

Assuming your data is shaped like:

```
{
  league: {
    groupNumber: 2
  },
  team: [
    {
      _id: 'TeamA',
      teamName: 'Team A'
    },
    {
      _id: 'TeamB',
      teamName: 'Team B'
    },
    {
      _id: 'TeamC',
      teamName: 'Team C'
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you need to "step-up" a context-level within the `#times` block in order to get `team` from the parent context with `../team`. The template becomes:

```
{{#times league.groupNumber}}
  <div class="grupDiv" style="width:150px;display:inline-block;border:1px solid black;padding:10px">
    <h2>Grup {{this}}</h2>
    <select name="" id="" multiple>
      {{#each ../team}}
        <option value="{{_id}}">{{teamName}}</option>
      {{/each}}
    </select>
   </div>
{{/times}}
```

```js
const template = Handlebars.compile(
`
{{#times league.groupNumber}}
  <div class="grupDiv" style="width:150px;display:inline-block;border:1px solid black;padding:10px">
    <h2>Grup {{this}}</h2>
    <select name="" id="" multiple>
      {{#each ../team}}
        <option value="{{_id}}">{{teamName}}</option>
      {{/each}}
    </select>
   </div>
{{/times}}
`);

Handlebars.registerHelper('times', function (n, block) {
  let accum = '';
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    accum += block.fn(i);
  return accum;
});

const data = {
  league: {
    groupNumber: 2
  },
  team: [
    {
      _id: 'TeamA',
      teamName: 'Team A'
    },
    {
      _id: 'TeamB',
      teamName: 'Team B'
    },
    {
      _id: 'TeamC',
      teamName: 'Team C'
    }
  ]
};

const output = template(data);

document.body.innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.7/handlebars.min.js"></script>
```

And [here](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/4g68er7y/) is the same code in a fiddle for reference.

Comment: Thank you sir, this worked perfectly but I got new problems. I added new code inside my code. Actually I want to "this" value in this code to be equal to "this" value of the top {{#times league.groupNumber}}.                                                                       ```{{#each ../league.groupNo{{this}} }}
                            <span> {{this.teamName}}</span>
                            {{/each}} ```

Comment: I thought that `league.groupNo` was a single value. If that is the case, it does not make sense to `#each` over it. Can you clarify what you are trying to do? (Again, sharing your data structure would be very helpful!)

Comment: Here is my part of the data structure (I'm showing some of it because it's too much): ```groupNumber: {type:Number}, groupNo1: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "team"}], groupNo2: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "team"}], groupNo3: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "team"}]```  I want to see the teams of each group. For example İnside of the Grup 1 box, I Want to see groupNo1's datas.

Comment: Also, I update my code on the question for you to understand better. At this code `<h2>Grup {{this}}</h2>` I want to use same `{{this}}` value for this: `{{#each ../league.groupNo{{this}}}}` But I got syntax error.

Comment: @atuna00: You need to open new questions when you have significant changes to your code. Now that you have changed the question, my answer does not make sense. Secondly, you need to provide enough information in your questions so that people can understand the issue. You need to share a simplified example of the data you are using. With what you have posted, I am forced to guess at what certain pieces of the data might look like. `../league.groupNo{{this}}` is invalid. You would need to create a custom helper to concatenate `"groupNo"` and `this`. See: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/s4dnqcxf/

Comment: Oh sorry, you're right, I will return my question to the first version. Also thank you for your solution worked perfectly.